# How can I invoke sendAndReceive when a flow contains different type of channels?

Tags: java, spring, integration, spring-integration

I have spent a few good amount of hours reading about Spring Integration. And today I started experimenting with the framework. There are aspects of how it works that I have trouble understanding despite of all my reading. I hope somebody here can put me back on tracks.

I have the following channel and endpoint defined:

```
<in:channel id="orderSource"/>
<in:service-activator input-channel="orderSource" 
                          ref="defaultOrderService"
                          method="placeOrder"/>
```

Since the channel is a DirectChannel I expect everything to happen within a single thread and get a return value at the end.

The `placeOrder` method look as follows:

```
@Override
public Order placeOrder(Order order) {
   return order;
}
```

In my main method I have:

```
MessageChannel input = context.getBean("orderSource", MessageChannel.class);
Message<Order> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Order(123)).build();
MessagingTemplate messenger = new MessagingTemplate(input);
Message<?> result = messenger.sendAndReceive(message);
Object found = result.getPayload();
```

And this all works like a charm. The `found` is the order the service activator sends back.

My problem starts when I want to notify a set of subscribers that the order was placed. For simplicity, let's do this synchronously, like this:

```
<in:channel id="orderSource"/>
<in:service-activator input-channel="orderSource"
                      output-channel="savedOrders"
                      ref="defaultOrderService"
                      method="validateOrder"/>

<in:publish-subscribe-channel id="savedOrders"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="savedOrders"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyCustomerService"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="savedOrders"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyShipmentManager"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="savedOrders"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyWarehouseManager"/>
```

The question now is what should the input channel expect in return when I invoke `sendAndReceive`?

My current code blocks and I never reach the end of the main thread.

How can I make sure I receive a reply containing the result of the service activator as it passed it to all subscribers?

Also I am really curious about what a given channel can expect in terms of returning values when there are asynchronous channels in the flow. I'd like to get the result at end of a transaction and before new thread is spawn, but I don't know how to do that.

Any thoughts, advice or guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your "notify" methods return null. If that's the case, there's no "reply" sent to the `MessagingTemplate`.

Make the final one return the order, or add a `<bridge/>` to nowhere as a fourth subscriber to the pub-sub channel.

A bridge to nowhere is simply a bridge with no output channel. When a message arrives at an endpoint that produces a reply, and there is no `output-channel`, the message's `replyChannel` header is used to route the reply to the originator.

It works with async channels too, but I'd need to understand your requirements there before I can provide guidance.

Also, consider using a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) on the calling side instead of building a message yourself and using the `MessagingTemplate`. Rather than exposing your caller to the messaging infrastructure, the framework will create a proxy for you that will take care of all that and you just interact with the POJI.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some more time reading and I discovered that this is all a matter of configuring the reply channel either in the message or in the gateway and using bridge just as Gary Rusell suggested did the trick for me.

This is my code, now working:

```
<in:channel id="arrivals"/>
<in:service-activator input-channel="arrivals"
                      output-channel="validated"
                      ref="defaultOrderService"
                      method="validateOrder"/>
<in:channel id="validated"/>
<in:service-activator input-channel="validated"
                      output-channel="persisted"
                      ref="defaultOrderService"
                      method="placeOrder"/>

<in:publish-subscribe-channel id="persisted"/>

<in:channel id="replyChannel"/>

<in:bridge input-channel="persisted"  output-channel="replyChannel"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="persisted"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyCustomerService"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="persisted"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyShipmentManager"/>

<in:outbound-channel-adapter channel="persisted"
                             ref="defaultOrderService"
                             method="notifyWarehouseManager"/>

<in:gateway id="orderService"
            service-interface="codemasters.services.OrderService"
            default-request-channel="arrivals"
            default-reply-channel="replyChannel"/>
```

And using a gateway, this all looks much cooler now:

```
OrderService service = context.getBean("orderService", OrderService.class);
Order result = service.validateOrder(new Order(4321));
```

Comment: Just an FYI; the subscribers will be invoked in the order that they are parsed by default; you can override this (or even just for documentation to make your intent clear) by adding an `order` attribute to each consuming endpoint (`order="1"` etc.).

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks Gary. This is my first encounter with Spring Integration. I am experimenting with all the options. I just changed the setup to use asynchronous notification of subscribers. This is looking cooler by the minute :-)